# Java 8 streams to split and collect tokens

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an input like this

```
abc|label1 cde|label2 xyz|label1 mno|label3 pqr|label2
```

And I want to create a string like this

```
"abc cde xyz mno pqr"
```

This is how far I got

```
 Arrays.stream(text.split(" "))
       .map(i -> i.split("\\|"))
       .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Why use streams for that, when a simple regex can do it? `result = text.replaceAll("\\|\\w+", "");`

Answer (score 3):

You are close, but you forgot to take just the first element of the `String` array returned by the inner `split`:

```
Arrays.stream(text.split(" "))
      .map(i -> i.split("\\|")[0])
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

This produces the desired `String`:

```
abc cde xyz mno pqr
```

Comment: Way overkill, creating 15 intermediate strings and 5 intermediate arrays plus the overhead of streaming, when you can just use regex: `text.replaceAll("\\|\\S+", "")` --- Especially since you're already using regex in the `split()` calls.

Comment: @Andreas also an overkill to write the same comment for both the question and the answer :) I just answered what's wrong with the OP's code and showed how to fix it.

Comment: However, there's exactly a point in what @Andreas says. So, it is extremely valid. The use of `String.split` is a very naive approach IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a different approach, I suggest using regular expressions. I use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) on a daily basis to build various expressions for my applications. Here's how I would use regex in your situation:

```
String input = "abc|label1 cde|label2 xyz|label1 mno|label3 pqr|label2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+(?=\\|)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
while(m.find()) {
    joiner.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```

You can also use [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas)' expression, which takes care of it in much fewer lines (I changed it a bit to compensate for the potential absence of white-space):

```
String input = "abc|label1 cde|label2 xyz|label1 mno|label3 pqr|label2";
input = String.join(" ", input.split("\\|\\w+\\d\\s*"));
System.out.println(input);
```

Both solutions produce the desired result:

```
abc cde xyz mno pqr
```